# What aspects of the Cloak of Many Fashions are changeable?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, equipment

Can you change the length and add pockets or similar additions or can you just change the design and the color on it?

Answer (score 2):

In 5th Edition a spell, ability or item does what the description says.

> While wearing this cloak, you can use a bonus action to change the style, color, and apparent quality of the garment. The cloak’s weight doesn’t change. Regardless of its appearance, ***the cloak can’t be anything but a cloak***. Although ***it can duplicate the appearance of other*** magic ***cloaks***, it doesn’t gain their magical properties.

The mention of change in style, quality, and that it can duplicate appearance of other (magic, but I assume also non-magic) cloaks makes me believe that if there are cloaks with pockets then this one can take that form.

The length of the cloak is part of style (fashion) change so the cloak could be either a long regal cloak or a short hooded cloak, among other options.